# Asp net Identity, calling AccountController from HomeController and trouble with UserMenager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

So I have successfully implemented Account controller and various methods that come with it. I have one specific method that returns AppUser (current user)

```
public AppUser GetCurrentUser(){
       AppUser user = UserMenager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
       return user; }.
```

Now I don't want to have instance of UserMenager in all of my controllers (or should I?), so in my HomeController I need to render a partial view based on is user logged in or not, so I call this method

```
public ActionResult RightNavigation()
        {   
            // account is instance of AccountController
            AppUser user = account.GetCurrentUser();

            if (user == null)
            {
                return PartialView("NavWhenNotLogged");
            }
            else
            {
                return PartialView("NavWhenLogged",user);
            }
        }
```

Problem is, I am getting NullException for the UserMenager instance in Account Controller :

```
private AppUserMenager UserMenager
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<AppUserMenager>();
            }
        }
```

Now I assume this is not the right way to 'share' UserMenager in different Controllers so If you could just give me 'the' way to this this.

In summary : I have Account controller that has various methods about users, etc. When I try to use one of those methods that relies on UserMenager, I get Null Exception for UserMenager.

Comment: how do you get the instance of the `AccountController`? also why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Startup class you need to call the following line inside Configuration method, which puts the instance of ApplicationUserManager into OwinContext for every request.

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<UserManager>(UserManager.Create);
    }
```

UserManager.Create() is a static method returns the instance.

Don't call controller from another controller. To get the UserManager you can do it in any controller's action:

```
    var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<UserManager>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Request.IsAuthenticated
```

In the default MVC5 project there is sample check for if user is logged in in the _LoginPartial.cshtml.